# animating a view in Android

Tags: android, animation, view, bitmap

I’d like to do something very basic, for having a kind of animation. So a loop like:

- Update bitmap
- Sleep 100ms
- Display bitmap "mabm" on a view

My code works only once, performing the first loop, and I can’t afford to find a solution for the others loops.
What is the simplest way to do that?
Thank you for your help!

**My code:**

```
Bitmap mabm= Bitmap.createBitmap(400,400,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(mabm);

/* more code here */

Taff=new Thread(new Runnable() { 

    // voir : android updating a view repeatedly

    @Override   
    public void run(){                                  
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //empty catch
        }

       deco.decompp() ;  // this method updates mabm        

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(mabm);
               ds.setBackgroundDrawable(d); 
           }                            
       }); 
    }
);
```

Comment: where is the loop in your code ?   I guess it miss this part.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this thread *Taff* is meant to be triggered by an other Thread (reading a smart card which is a slow device). 
But your question helped me to understand that *Taff.start()* doesn't trigger a new execution of Taff, and can't be used for this purpose.
So I changed the code of Taff, with a real loop, and now it works!
Thank you for your help.